# convert a big numpy array to string

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I was trying to convert a big NumPy array to a string by using `np.array_str()` or `str()` but it turns out that the output does not contain all the values of the array.

```
weight=np.random.rand(5000,500)
print(weight.shape)
print(len(np.array_str(weight)))
print(len(str(weight)))
>>(5000,500)
>>443
>>443
```

Which is way less than the actual count of digits.

How can I get the complete array as a string? 
N.B. I want to write the sting in a text file.

Comment: How are you going to use this file later? Do you intend to read it and recreate the array? If so how? Practice on a small array before wasting time on a large one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str(weight)` is just the console representation of the string, it does not convert *all* values to string values, instead it generates a string that can be printed to the console, e.g.:

```py
>>> str(weight)
'[[0.61063338 0.76216809 0.09732382 ... 0.74375515 0.09525192 0.43705637]\n [0.70583367 0.25657426 0.53279926 ... 0.72487029 0.36734946 0.67419836]\n [0.95006557 0.84218583 0.75602697 ... 0.51730571 0.11963987 0.84481707]\n ...\n [0.35017875 0.16172616 0.18016095 ... 0.74119508 0.09725982 0.93651959]\n [0.41584527 0.62796044 0.65794606 ... 0.12521724 0.62784847 0.57898542]\n [0.72758274 0.99773068 0.15162054 ... 0.42649996 0.631018   0.446582  ]]'
```

Try converting your array to a list and then to a string instead:

```py
str(weight.tolist())
```

Answer (score 1):

To generate a tab- and line-separated representation (if you accept this), you can do

```
with open("test.txt", "w") as fh: weight.tofile(fh, sep="\t")
```

Another way is to dump it as `json`, which is the same syntax as python code for a list:

```
from json import dump
with open("test.txt", "w") as fh: dump(weight.tolist(), fh)
```

I used `json` to make sure that nothing gets lost.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
conv_str = [[str(j) for j in i] for i in weight]
```